# elementary.io blocked in Russia

Tags: updates, elementary-website

104.28.5.44 and 104.28.4.44 in blocklist. Blocked by the state because of some other sites placed on IP. Check it out here http://blocklist.rkn.gov.ru/

Updates OS are not available. Please move your server to clean IP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they can migrate to a new IP that fast, but try calling them out on Twitter and/or filing an issue to their Github pages.

For the meantime, you can use a VPN (free VPN services will do since the updates probably won't take up more than 500MB) to fetch updates. Hope this helps.